# Chrome like tab switcher for Xamarin Android

Tags: java, c#, android, tabs, xamarin.android

Currently I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the Chrome tab switcher on Android.
So far I was only able to find the following library for native Android. Nothing exists for Xamarin Android.

[ChromeLikeTabSwitcher](https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher)

[image]

Has anyone came across a similar implementation? Any recommendations to start? I'm thinking of a **vertical view pager** but not sure if it's the right approach. Any advices would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any such library for xamarin but
if you want to convert this java library into a C# dll what you can do is check these links and follow the procedure :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Goodluck!